# Can I disable selection in specific UIPickerView item?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

I can find a post that teach to use delegate method to check if the row valid and then scroll to the right one if not.

But that's not I want. Can I disable the specific row after the pickerView initialized?
Like "Gray-out" the row and can't stop indicator on it.

Thank you, experts.

Answer (score 10):

There are two parts to doing this.

1. Use [`-[<UIPickerViewDelegate> pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006924-CH3-SW2) to return a custom view for each row, such as a `UILabel`. For the row you want to show up as disabled, you'll need to configure the view to reflect that disabledness.
2. In [`-[<UIPickerViewDelegate> pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006924-CH3-SW9), you'll need to detect when the disabled is selected, and then use [`-[UIPickerView selectRow:inComponent:animated:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006842-CH3-SW8) to "rollback" to a "valid" row.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just leave a blank in the implementation, e.g.:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if(row==0){
//Code
}
if(row==1){

//BLANK

}
if(row==2){
//Code
}
```